# Custom SSL Certificates with AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, asynchttpclient

A java application needs to make some requests to a server using a custom certificate. The OS contains another certificate for the given server, and it makes no difference if I add the custom cert file or not.

The flow is similar to

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig asyncHttpClientConfig = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig
    .Builder()
    .setMaxRequestRetry(1)
    .setMaxConnections(1)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(1)
    .setRequestTimeout(10000)
    .setConnectTimeout(10000)
    .setFollowRedirect(true)
    .setSslContext(buildSslContext())
    .build();

AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(asyncHttpClientConfig);

String url = "www.example.com"
ListenableFuture<Response> res = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).execute();
Response r = res.get();
System.out.println(r);
```

The `buildSslContext` method is

```
private static SslContext buildSslContext() {
    File pemFile = new File("/path/to/cert.pem");

    try {
        return SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(pemFile, pemFile).build();
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've also tested with `curl`

```
# curl -v www.example.com
# curl -v --cacert /path/to/cert.pem www.example.com
```

It makes no difference. But, if I do remove the content of `/etc/ssl/` it will not access the server at all.

Is there any possibility to specify a custom certificate for a given server and use the default ones from OS for other servers, with [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)? I use version 2.8.0 for async-http-client.

Comment: Usually you need two files, one with the certificate and one with the private key. Does `cert.pem` contains both? If yes try to split them.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it contains both. Why to split them?